# Uso di "che la metà basta" nel Sud Italia

Tags: idioms, regional

Spesso, quando sono nel nord Italia, sento l'espressione "che la metà basta", per esempio nelle seguenti frasi:

> C'è un chiasso che la metà basta.

> Sono così nauseato che la metà basta.

È l'espressione *de quo* usata anche nel sud d'Italia? Se non lo è, quale espressione è usata al Sud che è equivalente per colore e tono?

Quasi dimenticavo di spiegarne il significato; eccolo con riferimento alle frasi di cui sopra:

> C'è un chiasso infernale.

> Sono incredibilmente nauseato.

Comment: Puoi specificare il significato? Così ti posso dire se, almeno stando alla mia conoscenza, esiste un equivalente meridionale.

Comment: Nel primo caso vuol dire che c'è così tanto chiasso che anche la metà sarebbe già troppa.

Comment: martina, I edited the question in order to be more clear; and kiamla added another explanation in their comment.

Comment: Non sono sicura ma non credo che si usi al Sud. Inoltre, non mi viene in mente nessuna espressione equivalente. Vediamo se qualcuno ne sa di più.

Comment: Per quanto può valere, ho sempre avuto l'impressione di sentirlo usare maggiormente dal lato "nord-est" della mia famiglia (le mie nonne hanno entrambe origini Trentine).

Comment: Confermo che in Romagna (quindi sempre nord-est se vogliamo) si usa, anche se la forma che finisce con "basta" è a volte meno usata rispetto al condizionale "basterebbe".

Comment: Nel veneto viene utilizzata più "che metà basta" senza "la" vedi [qui](http://www.donzelli.it/libro/392/che-meta-basta) e [qui](http://books.google.it/books?id=jhVdAAAAMAAJ&q=che+met%C3%A0+basta&dq=che+met%C3%A0+basta&hl=it&sa=X&ei=RwmTUqfTJ4qk4gTboIGoBA&redir_esc=y).

Answer (score 9):

Essendo siciliano e frequentando diverse regioni del sud per lavoro, posso confermare che né in Sicilia, né in altre regioni del sud Italia la frase è comunemente utilizzata.

Per quanto riguarda frasi simili per colore e tono, non credo che se ne possa trovare una usata in *tutto* il sud Italia; per la mia esperienza, esistono numerose frasi per lo più dialettali, che quindi variano al variare del dialetto, il che vuol dire anche di città in città.

Comment: Puoi fare un esempio, dicci quella che useresti tu :-)!

Comment: Dalle mie parti la frase dialettale più usata è "Signuri bunu chiu", che in italiano sarebbe "Signore (inteso come Dio) basta così"